# View the document file in browser using iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Need to display the content such as pdf, docx, ppt, image etc,. using iframe tag.

Refer the sites for this through which we get this link

```
 <iframe class="doc" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://writing.engr.psu.edu/workbooks/formal_report_template.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Its displaying the content. But our content is from localhost or file(doc) in system stored.

```
 <iframe class="doc" src="easychair.docx"></iframe>
```

When we use like this document gets downloaded. Instead of downloading we need to show the content in browser itself.

Tried out another example for viewing the document that is present locally in the machine
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=C%3A%5CUsers%5C123456%5CDesktop%5CTTK.docx
Which results in showing an error page.

Please help us to find the solution for viewing the document. Tell me the ways to upload the local files to server. 
Is uploading like that a secure way?

Thanks in advance.I referred those previous answer also I didn't get any correct solution. 
Only the google link showing the document our local files gets simply downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your pdf(doc,ppt) files to Google drive.

1.Preview pdf file in Google Drive.

2.Click on Pop-out Preview.

3.select from options'embed code'.

4.Copy code.

5.Add into Your webpage.

**Other Source [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5SkbcId-v0) to Embed .Doc Files.**